Using PHP file to write to serial
I'm using the old php_serial.class.php that can be found here: text. I have changed the curly braces for square braces and I have used the following code in my other PHP file and this is the response "

[php:warn] [pid 1018:tid 1018] [client ::1:55892] PHP Warning: The
device must be set before to be open in
/var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 167, referer:
http://localhost./

any help is greatly appreciated:
<?php
include "php_serial.class.php";

$totalHundreds=$_POST['totalHundreds']; 
$totalTens=$_POST['totalTens']; 
$totalOnes=$_POST['totalOnes']; 
$wicketsOnes=$_POST['wicketsOnes']; 
$oversTens=$_POST['oversTens']; 
$oversOnes=$_POST['oversOnes']; 
$batsmanaHundreds=$_POST['batsmanaHundreds'];   
$batsmanaTens=$_POST['batsmanaTens'];   
$batsmanaOnes=$_POST['batsmanaOnes'];   
$batsmanbHundreds=$_POST['batsmanbHundreds'];   
$batsmanbTens=$_POST['batsmanbTens'];   
$batsmanbOnes=$_POST['batsmanbOnes'];   
$targetHundreds=$_POST['targetHundreds'];   
$targetTens=$_POST['targetTens'];   
$targetOnes=$_POST['targetOnes'];   

$total=$totalHundreds.$totalTens.$totalOnes;
$overs=$oversTens.$oversOnes;
$batsmana=$batsmanaHundreds.$batsmanaTens.$batsmanaOnes;
$batsmanb=$batsmanbHundreds.$batsmanbTens.$batsmanbOnes;
$target=$targetHundreds.$targetTens.$targetOnes;


$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
#$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");
$serial->confBaudRate(57600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$tempString="4,".$batsmana.",".$total.",".$batsmanb.",".$wicketsOnes.",".$overs.",".$target."#";
#echo($tempString."<br>");
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage($tempString);


$serial->deviceClose();

echo("Total: " . $total . " for " . $wicketsOnes . " wickets from " . $overs . " overs. Target: " . $target . ". Batsman A is on: " . $batsmana . " Batsman B is on: " .$batsmanb);

print_r($_POST);
?>

I've checked and 'admin'(not www-data) is the user of the PHP and I've added it to the dialout, I've checked the dialout group to confirm, I've tried:
$serial = new phpSerial;
    $serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
    #$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");
    $serial->confBaudRate(57600);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);

But it doesn't appear to give control to the Serial device as in it wont open.
Here's the response:
object(phpSerial)#1 (7) {
["_device"]=>
NULL
["_windevice"]=>
NULL
["_dHandle"]=>
NULL
["_dState"]=>
int(0)
["_buffer"]=>
string(0) ""
["_os"]=>
string(0) ""
["autoflush"]=>
bool(true)
}


We can not really help you with this information. You will need to debug '->deviceOpen' and solve errors happening there. If you can't solve those, then make a ticket about that (or edit this one)
